# How to fetch only a field in the incoming observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I have an observable that I use as follows.

```
...
const id = 1337;
this.service.getThing(id).subscribe(
  suc => doSomething(suc.name),
  err = doSomethingElse()
);
```

Since I've started to use the async pipe, I do most of my observables like this.

```
thing$: Observable<Thing>;
...
ngOnInit(){
  this.thing$ = this.service.getThing(1337);
}
```

I can use the result in the HTML as shown below but I'm curious if it's possible to declare an operation that, when realized, gets the value from observable and only picks a certain field.

```
<div *ngIf="thing$ | async as thing>
  {{thing.name}}
</div>
```

I'd like to access only the name instead having to pull it out from the thing.

I've tried playing around with *pipe(...)* because my suspicion tells me that there's something to it. I didn't make it work, though and lost confidence, since I'm not even sure that's the poassible approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RxJS [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator for that:

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

thingName$: Observable<string>;

ngOnInit(){
  this.thingName$ = this.service.getThing(1337).pipe(map(thing => thing.name));
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="thingName$ | async as thingName>
  {{thingName}}
</div>
```

Comment: I was **so** close with my attempt. For some reason I used *Map* with capital letter... And then I gave up.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [pluck](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/pluck) from the rxjs library.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ProductService } from '../shared/product.service';
import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-product',
    template: `<div *ngIf="productName$ | async as productName">
          {{productName}}
        </div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    productName$: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.productName$ = this.productService.getProduct(1).pipe(pluck('productName'));
    }

}
```

This example plucks the product name from a product returned from the product service.

```
export interface Product {
    id: number;
    productCode: string;
    productName: string;
}
```

Comment: Is *pluck*ing syntactic sugar for the *map*ing suggested by @connersfan or is there more depth to it? (So I know if I should head to the docs and read up on it or simply use whichever I fancy the most.)

Comment: The docs describe it like this: *Like map, but meant only for picking one of the nested properties of every emitted object.* So, I think calling it syntactic sugar would be a good call.